# Search query works in local and some filters does not work in production for Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, namecheap

I have a query script for Laravel that does multiple search filtering algorithm. The search filters all work perfectly on local, but on production, when a keyword is entered, it correctly checks for model relationships, but does not check for data on the listings table directly. The same code works perfectly on local, at first, I thought it was a code issue, but am not sure anymore.

The production server has the following configurations:

- Server version: 10.5.20-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
- Protocol version: 10
- PHP Version: 8.0

While the PHPMyAdmin reports the global server PHP settings which is different from my domain: the global PHP version is 7.4.27.

On my local, the versions are:

- Server version: 8.0.32 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
- Protocol version: 10

Here is the code that searches.

```
public static function listings(Request $request)
{
    try{
    $initialData = Listing::query()
    ->select(
        'listings.*',
        'states.name as state_name',
        'sub_categories.sub_category_name',
        'sub_categories.is_land'
    )
    ->leftJoin('states', 'listings.state_id', 'states.id')
    ->leftJoin('sub_categories', 'listings.sub_category_id', 'sub_categories.id')
    ->when($request->has('brand_id'))->where('brand_id', $request->brand)
    ->when($request->has('brand'), function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->join('brands', 'listings.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
            ->where('brands.brand_name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->brand}%");
    })
    ->when($request->has('listing_type'))->listingType(\strtolower($request->listing_type))
    ->withCasts(['is_land' => 'boolean']);

    $result = $initialData
        ->when($request->has('subcategory'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $subcategories = Str::of($request->subcategory)->explode(',');
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($subcategories) {
                /** @var string[] $subcategories */
                foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('sub_categories.sub_category_name', 'LIKE', "%{$subcategory}%");
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has('payment_plan'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $requestedPaymentPlans = Str::of($request->payment_plan)->explode(',')->toArray();
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($requestedPaymentPlans) {
                foreach ($requestedPaymentPlans as $paymentPlan) {
                    $subquery->orWhereJsonContains('payment_plan', $paymentPlan);
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has('space_type'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $space_type = Str::of($request->space_type)->explode(',');
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($space_type) {
                /** @var string[] $space_type */
                foreach ($space_type as $space) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('listings.space_type', 'LIKE', "%{$space}%");
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has(['min_price', 'max_price']))->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereBetween('listings.price', [$request->query('min_price'), $request->query('max_price')]);
        })
        ->when($request->has('location'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            /** @var string[] $location */
            $location = Str::of($request->location)->explode(' ');
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($location) {
                foreach ($location as $loc) {
                    $subquery->orWhereHas('state', function ($q) use ($loc) {
                        $q->where('states.name', 'LIKE', "%{$loc}%");
                    })
                        ->orWhereHas('country', function ($q) use ($loc) {
                            $q->where('countries.name', 'LIKE', "%{$loc}%");
                        })
                        ->orWhere('listings.full_address', 'LIKE', "%{$loc}%")
                        ->orWhere('listings.city', 'LIKE', "%{$loc}%");
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has('keyword'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            /** @var string[] $keywords */
            $keywords = Str::of($request->keyword)->explode(' ');
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($keywords) {
                foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('listings.listing_caption', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
                        ->orWhere('listings.listing_description', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
                        ->orWhereHas('state', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                            $q->where('states.name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
                        })
                        ->orWhereHas('country', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                            $q->where('countries.name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
                        })
                        ->orWhere('listings.city', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
                        ->orWhere('listings.full_address', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
                        ->orWhereHas('sub_category', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                            $q->where('sub_categories.sub_category_name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
                        });
                }
            });
        })
        ->get();

    $landResults = $result->where('is_land', true);
    $nonLandResults = $result->where('is_land', false);

    $finalResult = collect([]);
    $filteredNonLandResults = collect([]);

    if ($nonLandResults->isEmpty()) {
        if ($landResults->isEmpty()) {
            $finalResult = $initialData->get();
        }
    }else {
        $filteredNonLandResults = $nonLandResults->when($request->has('bathrooms'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('listings.bathrooms', $request->bathrooms);
        })
        ->when($request->has('bedrooms'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('listings.bedrooms', $request->bedrooms);
        })
        ->when($request->has('condition'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $condition = Str::of($request->condition)->explode(',');

            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($condition) {
                /** @var string[] $condition */
                foreach ($condition as $cond) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('listings.condition', 'LIKE', "%{$cond}%");
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has('furnishing'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $furnishings = Str::of($request->furnishing)->explode(',');

            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($furnishings) {
                /** @var string[] $furnishings */
                foreach ($furnishings as $furnishing) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('listings.furnishing', 'LIKE', "%{$furnishing}%");
                }
            });
        });
        $finalResult = $landResults->concat($filteredNonLandResults)->values()->all();
    }

    $queryLog = DB::getQueryLog();
    Log::info($queryLog);

    return $finalResult;
    }catch(\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I also echoed out the query in the log, and it looks really fine, in fact, running it directly on the database engine in production, it brings the desired result, but the endpoint returns very unstable results, it works in weird ways.

Imagine searching space_type using the value 'private' I get results, then change it to 'shared' which also exists, it returns empty array.

**Edited from here**

On the production, the query log sample for when only the keyword parameter is supplied is:

```
[2023-12-07 14:28:19] production.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select `listings`.*, `states`.`name` as `state_name`, `sub_categories`.`sub_category_name`, `sub_categories`.`is_land` from `listings` left join `states` on `listings`.`state_id` = `states`.`id` left join `sub_categories` on `listings`.`sub_category_id` = `sub_categories`.`id` where (`listings`.`listing_caption` LIKE ? or `listings`.`listing_description` LIKE ? or exists (select * from `states` where `listings`.`state_id` = `states`.`id` and `states`.`name` LIKE ?) or exists (select * from `countries` where `listings`.`country_id` = `countries`.`id` and `countries`.`name` LIKE ?) or `listings`.`city` LIKE ? or `listings`.`full_address` LIKE ? or exists (select * from `sub_categories` where `listings`.`sub_category_id` = `sub_categories`.`id` and `sub_categories`.`sub_category_name` LIKE ?))',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => '%near%',
      1 => '%near%',
      2 => '%near%',
      3 => '%near%',
      4 => '%near%',
      5 => '%near%',
      6 => '%near%',
    ),
    'time' => 6.28,
  ),
)
```

while on local, this is the query log:

```
[2023-12-07 14:38:50] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select `listings`.*, `states`.`name` as `state_name`, `sub_categories`.`sub_category_name`, `sub_categories`.`is_land` from `listings` left join `states` on `listings`.`state_id` = `states`.`id` left join `sub_categories` on `listings`.`sub_category_id` = `sub_categories`.`id` where (`listings`.`listing_caption` LIKE ? or `listings`.`listing_description` LIKE ? or exists (select * from `states` where `listings`.`state_id` = `states`.`id` and `states`.`name` LIKE ?) or exists (select * from `countries` where `listings`.`country_id` = `countries`.`id` and `countries`.`name` LIKE ?) or `listings`.`city` LIKE ? or `listings`.`full_address` LIKE ? or exists (select * from `sub_categories` where `listings`.`sub_category_id` = `sub_categories`.`id` and `sub_categories`.`sub_category_name` LIKE ?))',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => '%near%',
      1 => '%near%',
      2 => '%near%',
      3 => '%near%',
      4 => '%near%',
      5 => '%near%',
      6 => '%near%',
    ),
    'time' => 152.35,
  ),
)
```

Comment: maybe the issue is not on the query, but on the collection filtering you do after?

Comment: also there is no "LIKE" operator to filter on a collection. seems like you are mixing up the query builder with collections, `$nonLandResults` is a collection not a query builder.

Comment: I am not so sure the problem lies in the filter on the collection for the $nonLandResults, like I said, it works very correctly when run on localhost.

Comment: Comparing collations would be a good start. You might be running a non-ci collation, for example. Are the data in the database exactly the same? Another thing to look into is optimization flags between local and production. A https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would help to pinpoint the exact query that's different. Would you also be able to paste the query log for both local and production?

Comment: @JosephOkafor "I am not so sure the problem lies in the filter on the collection" - well you said that "running it directly on the database engine in production, it brings the desired result" so based on that the filtering must be happening after the query.

Comment: @soulseekah I have added the query log. Please what do you think?

Comment: @soulseekah I also noticed that when I exported the table from production and then copied the insert command to insert some data from production to local, it inserted successfully, but here is the catch, searching those new records returned empty arrays, but the old records are still coming out in the search results. Do you know why?

Comment: @krisgjika also please leave your comment on why the data is not being returned in local when the it was inserted from production. Also, am not sure I understood your last statement about the filtering happening after the query.

Comment: does running the query in a sql console return the desired result?

Comment: @krisgjika Yes it does

Comment: @JosephOkafor than why do you think the problem is on the query? If the query is returning the correct data, only something altering that data after the query can clear it

Comment: I don't have clear explanations, let me try something

Comment: Yeah @krisgjika something is indeed manipulating the data, I returned the results at the top part after getting the $results, and it actually showed the data. When I am done, will share the final code for references. Your hint at the code logic did the trick eventually.

Answer (score 0):

After some good hints from Kris, I understood that it was the code logic that had the challenge. At some point in the lifecycle of the logic, the results fetched were overwritten. So here is the code fix that works for all search params.

```
public static function listings(Request $request)
{
    try{
    $initialData = Listing::query()
    ->select(
        'listings.*',
        'states.name as state_name',
        'sub_categories.sub_category_name',
        'sub_categories.is_land'
    )
    ->leftJoin('states', 'listings.state_id', 'states.id')
    ->leftJoin('sub_categories', 'listings.sub_category_id', 'sub_categories.id')
    ->when($request->has('listing_type'))->listingType(\strtolower($request->listing_type))
    ->withCasts(['is_land' => 'boolean']);

    $result = $initialData
        ->when($request->has('brand'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->join('brands', 'listings.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
                ->where('brands.brand_name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->brand}%");
        })
        ->when($request->has('subcategory'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $subcategories = Str::of($request->subcategory)->explode(',');
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($subcategories) {
                /** @var string[] $subcategories */
                foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('sub_categories.sub_category_name', 'LIKE', "%{$subcategory}%");
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has('payment_plan'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $requestedPaymentPlans = Str::of($request->payment_plan)->explode(',')->toArray();
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($requestedPaymentPlans) {
                foreach ($requestedPaymentPlans as $paymentPlan) {
                    $subquery->orWhereJsonContains('payment_plan', $paymentPlan);
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has('space_type'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $space_type = Str::of($request->space_type)->explode(',');
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($space_type) {
                /** @var string[] $space_type */
                foreach ($space_type as $space) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('listings.space_type', 'LIKE', "%{$space}%");
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has(['min_price', 'max_price']))->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereBetween('listings.price', [$request->query('min_price'), $request->query('max_price')]);
        })
        ->when($request->has('location'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            /** @var string[] $location */
            $location = Str::of($request->location)->explode(' ');
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($location) {
                foreach ($location as $loc) {
                    $subquery->orWhereHas('state', function ($q) use ($loc) {
                        $q->where('states.name', 'LIKE', "%{$loc}%");
                    })
                        ->orWhereHas('country', function ($q) use ($loc) {
                            $q->where('countries.name', 'LIKE', "%{$loc}%");
                        })
                        ->orWhere('listings.full_address', 'LIKE', "%{$loc}%")
                        ->orWhere('listings.city', 'LIKE', "%{$loc}%");
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has('keyword'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            /** @var string[] $keywords */
            $keywords = Str::of($request->keyword)->explode(' ');
            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($keywords) {
                foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('listings.listing_caption', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
                        ->orWhere('listings.listing_description', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
                        ->orWhereHas('state', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                            $q->where('states.name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
                        })
                        ->orWhereHas('country', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                            $q->where('countries.name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
                        })
                        ->orWhereHas('brand', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                            $q->where('brands.brand_name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
                        })
                        ->orWhere('listings.city', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
                        ->orWhere('listings.full_address', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
                        ->orWhereHas('sub_category', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                            $q->where('sub_categories.sub_category_name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
                        });
                }
            });
        })
        ->get();

    $landResults = $result->where('is_land', true);
    $nonLandResults = $result->where('is_land', false);

    $finalResult = collect([]);
    $filteredNonLandResults = collect([]);

    if (!$nonLandResults->isEmpty()) {
        $filteredNonLandResults = $nonLandResults->when($request->has('bathrooms'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('listings.bathrooms', $request->bathrooms);
        })
        ->when($request->has('bedrooms'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('listings.bedrooms', $request->bedrooms);
        })
        ->when($request->has('condition'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $condition = Str::of($request->condition)->explode(',');

            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($condition) {
                /** @var string[] $condition */
                foreach ($condition as $cond) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('listings.condition', 'LIKE', "%{$cond}%");
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->has('furnishing'), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $furnishings = Str::of($request->furnishing)->explode(',');

            $query->where(function ($subquery) use ($furnishings) {
                /** @var string[] $furnishings */
                foreach ($furnishings as $furnishing) {
                    $subquery->orWhere('listings.furnishing', 'LIKE', "%{$furnishing}%");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    $finalResult = $landResults->concat($filteredNonLandResults)->values()->all();

    if(count($finalResult) < 1) {
        $finalResult = $initialData->get();
    }

    return $finalResult;
    }catch(\Exception $e) {
        return "An error occurred";
    }
}
```

Comment: it is maybe better to explain the exact issue and the relevant piece of code that was incorrect, rather than dumping all of the code as an answer